# New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and iOS SDK

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to the app store using Xcode 7.3.1 on OS X 10.11.4.

While submitting app for approval I am getting following error.

> "New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta OS X builds."

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: just get a non-beta version of xcode...

Comment: are you working on some beta version or VMware?

Comment: Use Xcode 7.3 instead.

Comment: I am receiving this exact same error when trying to submit build for review on itunesconnect.apple.com. Versions of various things I have are: OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4; Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175); iOS SDK 9.3 (13E230). None of those are beta from what I am aware. What other software should I be looking at to ensure I am not running beta stuff?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: @user5938635 What's VMware got to do with it?

Answer (score 5):

Due to resolved app archives issue, Apple has depricated Xcode 8.3, so the app archives built with 8.3 will no longer be accepted by the App Store. Download latest stable version of Xcode i.e Version 8.3.2 or newer, rebuilt your app and resubmit.

[image]

Comment: I Uploaded with Xcode 8.3.2 and it worked for me. Try out!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the correct thing to do but as mentioned on https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23534 the following works:

> - Archive a new build, with a new build number
> - Find the archive in the organizer > right click > show in Finder
> - Right click on the archive > Show package contents
> - Navigate to Products > Applications > Right click on your app > Show package contents
> - Open Info.plist
> - Modify BuildMachineOSBuild to 14F27
> - Modify DTPlatformBuild to 13A340
> - Save Info.plist
> - Submit the archive in Xcode

This will make iTunes Connect think you built your app on Yosemite GM and iOS 9 GM and resolve the submit for review error. Not sure if it will cause any issues when apple actually come to review the app though.

Comment: it just went thru :) lemme see if it passes verification and gets published

Comment: @ZekeDran Did it submit successfully?

Comment: this was long ago, and yeah it got submitted successfully. But now things would have changed